# Controling from below

Tags: riddle, word

People almost always look down on me

Yet I have been controlling them more and more as of late

When I disappear you all feel alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is:

> Phone/mobile device

People always look down on me

> Texting/gaming

Yet I have been controlling them more and more as of late

> People are getting addicted. It's a common conception amongst the older generations that we are being "controlled" by our phones/mobile devices.

When I disappear, you all feel alone

> No phone = no social media = very lonely and bored and alone. Only a millennial would understand the feeling :P

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I was thinking.

Answer (score 2):

> The law

People almost always look down on me

> it's always convenient to whine about the law and law enforcement

Yet I have been controlling them more and more as of late

> you have to obey the law. "as of late" might be referring to surveillance agencies we are hearing of these days

When I disappear you all feel alone.

> if we abolished the rules altogether it would be like in The Purge

Answer (score 0):

Answer is

> **EARTH**

Explanation below:

People almost always look down on me

> People always look down to earth

Yet I have been controlling them more and more as of late

> Earth is always controlling us. Especially lately when we die and buried.

When I disappear you all feel alone.

> Once you fly up (on an aircraft or when people die) from earth one will definitely feel alone.

Comment: where is the explanation?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: Oh I see, I suppose that makes some sense, although the middle part is a little weird.